# chartjs how to disable value label above bar lines

Tags: angular, chart.js

Somethimes I get `NaN %` as bar values from my chart (totally random). I want to avoid it, but can't find a solution to hide these errors. To make it dissapear, I need to refresh the page.

This is happening for all the charts from app, not only for this. I'm pretty sure I need to update some options?!?!

```
angular v11.0.4 
chartjs v2.9.4
```

I added code for an options example:

```
public chartOptions: any = {
    responsive: true,
    responsiveAnimationDuration: 0,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    fill: true,
    hover: { mode: null },
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      align: 'start',
      labels: {
        boxWidth: 10,
        padding: 20,
        usePointStyle: true
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          color: '#D8D8D8'
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Date'
        },
        ticks: {
          display: true
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [
        {
          id: 'A',
          position: 'right',
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Visits'
          },
          ticks: {
            display: true,
            beginAtZero: true,
            autoSkip: true,
            stepSize: 50,
            maxTicksLimit: 15
          }
        },
        {
          id: 'B',
          position: 'left',
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Users'
          },
          ticks: {
            display: true,
            beginAtZero: true,
            autoSkip: true,
            stepSize: 5,
            maxTicksLimit: 15
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

[image: Invalid chart - NaN error img]

[image: Valid chart]

Comment: Could you share your code so we can try to troubleshoot the problem better?

Comment: thx for comment. updated right now with the `options` object

Comment: @AlleXyS Are you on which version of chart.js and angular ?